# How to revert a function in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I am building a little game and got stuck in developing the leveling system. I created a function that will exponentially increase the experience required for the next level. However, I am not sure how to turn it around so that I can put in the amount of experience a user has gained and get the corresponding level.

#### PHP function

```
function experience($level, $curve = 300) {

    // Preset value to prevent notices
    $a = 0;

    // Calculate level cap
    for ($x = 1; $x < $level; $x++) {
        $a += floor($x+$curve*pow(2, ($x/7)));
    }

    // Return amount of experience
    return floor($a/4);
}
```

#### The issue

I am wondering how I can reverse engineer this function in order to return the correct level for a certain amount of experience.

Using the above function, my code would output the following:

```
Level 1: 0
Level 2: 83
Level 3: 174
Level 4: 276
Level 5: 388
Level 6: 512
Level 7: 650
Level 8: 801
Level 9: 969
Level 10: 1154
```

What I am looking for is a way to invert this function so that I can input a certain amount and it will return the corresponding level.

A 1000 experience should return level 9 for example.

Comment: what do you expect as result(s) for certain levels of expirience? Input and output example(s) will be helpful.

Comment: @mitkosoft I'm sorry my question was a bit unclear. I have edited it.

Comment: thanks, @Peter, but again I don't see what do you need/expect as levels for your system? And in general - why do you need to use this function as you can create your own algorithm?

Comment: @mitkosoft Look at the supplied answers. That's what I was lookig for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plugging the values into excel and creating a trend line, I got the following equation:

```
y = 1.17E-09x^3 - 4.93E-06x^2 + 1.19E-02x + 6.43E-02
```

So your reverse engineered equation would be

```
function level($xp) {
    $a = 1.17e-9;
    $b = -4.93e-6;
    $c = 0.0119;
    $d = 0.0643

    return round($a*pow($xp, 3) + $b*pow($xp,2) + $c * $xp + $d);
}
```

Results are accurate to within 1dp, but if your `$curve` changes, you'd need to recalculate. I also haven't extended higher than level 10.

Other options include caching the results of the lookup:

```
$levelXpAmounts = array()

function populateLevelArray($curve=300) {
    $levelXpAmounts[$curve] = array();
    for($level = $minlevel; $level <= $maxLevel; $level++) {
        $levelXpAmounts[$curve][$level] = experience($level);
    }
}

//at game load:
populateLevelArray()
```

Then, your reverse lookup would be

```
function level($xp, $curve=300) {
    if (!array_key_exists($levelXpAmounts, curve) 
        populateLevelArray($curve);

    for($level = $minlevel; $ level <= $maxLevel; $level++) {
        if ($xp < $levelXpAmounts[$curve][$level]) {
            return $level - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, the iteration through all the levels is only done once for each different value of `$curve`. You can also replace your old `experience()` function with a (quite likely faster) lookup.

**Note**: it's been a while since I've written any php, so my syntax may be a little rusty. I apologize in advance for any errors in that regard.

Comment: Nice answer. This answers my question the way I expected it.

Comment: The huge problem that I see here is that Roadie approximates the exponential function with a cubic function which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @SalvadorDali within the 10 levels listed, the cubic curve has R^2 of 1.000. If we wanted to accurately model the xp -> level curve, you'd need a logarithmic equation, which I don't have the means to calculate. If you have a closed domain, a polynomial curve can be close *enough*.

Comment: @RoadieRich the thing is that the more levels you add, the more complex and uglier the equation becomes (changing all the coefficients completely). The code looks strange with many magic numbers all around. On the other hand this can be solved obviously with a simple binary search or if a binary search is too hard, just with a simple array iteration. The code is obvious and it will take 1 minute for any reasonable person to understand what is going on.

Comment: @SalvadorDali The levels come from magic numbers to start with.  Do you propose to eliminate those, too?

Answer (score 4):

You can do another function called `level` which uses the `experience` function to find the level:

```
function level($experience)
{ 
    for ($level = 1; $level <= 10; $level++) {
        if ($experience <= experience($level)) {
            return $level;
        }
    }
}

function experience($level, $curve = 300)
{
    $a = 0;
    for ($x = 1; $x < $level; $x++) {
        $a += floor($x+$curve*pow(2, ($x/7)));
    }
    return floor($a/4);
}

var_dump(level(1000));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can clearly work the math here and find a reverse formula. Not sure whether it will be a nice and easy formula, so I would suggest you an alternative approach which is easy to implement.

Precalculate the results for all the levels you realistically want your person to achieve (I highly doubt that you need more than 200 levels, because based on my estimation you will need tens of billions exp points).

Store all these levels in the array: `$arr = [0, 83, 174, 276, 388, 512, 650, ...];`. Now your array is sorted and you need to find a position where your level should fit.

If you are looking for 400 exp points, you see that it should be inserted after 5-th position - so it is 5-th level. Even a simple loop will suffice, but you can also write a binary search.

Answer (score 2):

This task could be solved in other way. This is method of partial sums.

Let's assume, you have a class , which stores an array of exponential values calculated by function:

```
function formula($level, $curve){ return floor($level+$curve*pow(2, ($level/7)));}

$MAX_LEVEL = 90;
function calculateCurve($curve){ 
  $array = [];
  for($i =0; $i< $MAX_LEVEL; $i++) $array.push(formula($i, $curve));
  return $array;
}
```

Now we can calculate experience, needed for a level:

```
$curve =  calculateCurve(300);
function getExperienceForLevel($level, $curve){
  $S = 0;
  for($i =0; $i < level; $i++) $S += $curve[$i];
}
```

And calculate level for experience:

```
function getLevelForExperience($exp, $curve){
  for($i =0; $i < $MAX_LEVEL; $i++){
     $exp -= $curve[$i];
     if($exp < 0) return $i-1; 
  }
  return $MAX_LEVEL;
}
```

I assume there could index problems - I didn't tested the code, but I suppose that main idea is clearly explained.

Pros:

- Code cleaner, There no magic numbers and interpolation coeficients.
- You can easy change your learning curve.
- Possibility to improve and make calculating functions as O(1);

Cons:

- There is an `$curve` array to store, or calculate somewhere.

Also. you could make even more advanced version of this:

```
function calculateCurve($curve){ 
  $array = [];
  $exp = 0;
  for($i =0; $i< $MAX_LEVEL; $i++) {
      $exp += formula($i, $curve);
      $array.push($exp);
   }
  return $array;
}
```

Now calculating experience have O(1) complexity;

```
function getExperienceForLevel($level, $curve){
  return $curve[min($MAX_LEVEL, $level)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best way, but it's working.

```
function level($experience, $curve = 300)
{
    $minLevel = 1;
    $maxLevel = 10;

    for($level = $minLevel; $level <= $maxLevel; $level++)
    {
        if(experience($level, $curve) <= $experience && $experience < experience($level + 1, $curve))
        {
            return $level;
        }
    }

    return $maxLevel;
}
```

Comment: I have been thinking about this approach myself. I guess there is no `effecient` way to reverse engineer this.

Comment: How often do you intend to call this function, say per minute? For code that is called once every 10 seconds or so, this is efficient enough.